# Problem with Microsoft Compiler macro expansion spaces

Tags: c, windows, visual-c++

I have this problem in a header macro expansion under Microsoft C Compiler Preprocessor:

custom.h

```
.
.

# define _OTHER_INCLUDE_DIR C:\3rdparty\usr\include

# define _3RD_PARTY_HEADERS(headername) <_OTHER_INCLUDE_DIR\headername>
.
.
```

With a header test:

headertest.h

```
.
.

#include _3RD_PARTY_HEADERS(stdint.h)
.
```

Microsoft C preprocessor expand second line like(custom.h):

```
#include  <C:\3rdparty\usr\include\headername>
```

If I set :

```
# define _3RD_PARTY_HEADERS(headername) <_OTHER_INCLUDE_DIR\ headername>
```

The result is:

```
#include  <C:\3rdparty\usr\include\ stdint.h>
```

How I can fix that?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to juxtapose your directory and your header name. You use `##`, like this:

```
# define _3RD_PARTY_HEADERS(headername) <_OTHER_INCLUDE_DIR\\##headername>
```

Comment: The result is : #include  <C:\3rdparty\usr\include\#"stdint.h">

Comment: @user: Oops, it looks like the compiler sees the backslash as an escape. Add an extra one, as I show in my edited post.

Answer (score 0):

Is there no way to have the `\` character sequences to be represented differently? The problem is that this is an escape character for C and C++. C99 explicitly states

> If the characters ', \, ", //, or /*
>   occur in the sequence between the <
>   and > delimiters, the behavior is
>   undefined.

(There is a similar phrase for `"..."` includes.)

and I imagine that for C++ there must be something similar. So maybe you just could use `/` and the compiler would replace them internally to refer to the correct file on your system.

Answer (score 0):

You know, most compilers have a command-line argument to add to the include path... -I or /I most likely for the Microsoft one. One doesn't usually do what you're doing here, never mind whether or not you can make it work.